# How to Enable the context sensitive help in eclipse rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I wanted to enable context sensitive help in my eclipse rcp application.
By context sensitive help, i mean that question mark in round circle that comes at left corner, every time you open a wizard page, like when you do New->java project.
I used:
**PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayDynamicHelp();**
in 
**public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer workbenchConfigurer)** method in **WorkbenchAdivisor.java**, but no use. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it !!
I added
**WizardDialog.setDialogHelpAvailable(true);** in WorkbenchAdvisor.java
WizardDialog is imported by: 
**import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog;**

Comment: @SidCool I will ! but i cant accept it for another few hours as i have accepted it once a while ago.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  Please do it once you are able to.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Harsha!  Little things contribute a big way to an open community.